# Dynamically add images to jQuery from xml

Tags: jquery, xml, image, slideshow

I am trying to add a series of images from an XML file into html and display them as a slideshow. I have the slideshow code working, however only the first image is added. The images are called "Slide1.png", "Slide2.png", etc. However, when I replace `$('body').append('<div id="container" />');` with `$('body').append('<div />');` and `$('#container').append($(pic));` with `$('div').append($(pic));` it works, but I'm not sure why.

The jQuery code is below:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function()
      {
        var temp = "";
        var i = 1;
        $.get('myData.xml', function(d){

        $('body').append('<div id="container" />');

        var fcn = $(d).find('picture').each(function(){

            var $image = $(this);
            var title = $picture.attr("title");
            var imageurl = $picture.attr('imageurl');
            var time_duration = $picture.attr("time_duration");

            var pic = '<li> <img class="bookImage" alt="" src="' + "images/Slide" + i + ".png "+ '" /> </li>';
            $('#container').append($(pic));
            i++;


        });
    });

// Slideshow Code
// ...
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few suggestions to your sample code that might help with this problem.

```
//adding a ul to contain the li, this may not be needed
$('body').append('<div id="container"><ul/></div>');

    //add your index variable to the each function if it is needed
    var fcn = $(d).find('picture').each(function(i){

        //variable was previously named $image, but was not used.
        var $picture= $(this);
        var title = $picture.attr("title");
        var imageurl = $picture.attr('imageurl');
        var time_duration = $picture.attr("time_duration");

        //make pic a jquery variable to simplify attribute setting
        var pic = $('<li> <img class="bookImage" alt=""/> </li>');
        pic.attr(src,imageurl); //prefix with path if needed

        //add results to the ul
        $('#container ul').append(pic);
     });
```